# Getting data from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I don't get how to get data from an array filled with objects in Javascript. Here is my code and error message :

```
//First I create the table
var dataset = [];

//Then I declare the object
var PersReunionObj = {};

//Now I throw some data into the object
PersReunionObj.fk_idPers = fk_idPers;
PersReunionObj.fk_idReunion = fk_idReunion;
PersReunionObj.isPresent = isPresent;

//I insert the object into a table    
dataset[0] = PersReunionObj;
```

Now I would like to get back those data from my table

```
console.log(dataset[0]);
```

Gives me :

{fk_idPers: 1, fk_idReunion: 1, isPresent: true}

So my table is OK. But then to get data, i tried something like

```
console.log(dataset[0].PersReunionObj.fk_idPers);
```

And it gives me an error :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fk_idPers' of undefined

How can i fix that ?

Comment: `dataset[0] = PersReunionObj` so `dataset[0]` *is* the `PersReunionObj`. Do `dataset[0].fk_idPers`

Comment: You might want to read about how to [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212).

Comment: Yes thanks, i'll have a look at that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to call because `dataset[0]` is `PersReunionObj`

```
console.log(dataset[0].fk_idPers);
```

Comment: Oh thanks, it's right it works.I feel a bit stupid right now :/

Comment: @Ishiru- No worries. When learning everyone ought to think and ask :)